# Convert image to a matrix in python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to do some image processing using Python.

Is there a simple way to import `.png` image as a matrix of greyscale/RGB values (possibly using PIL)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`scipy.misc.imread()` will return a Numpy array, which is handy for lots of things.

Comment: matplotlib.imread reads .png s (only) even without PIL installed.

Comment: this answer is 13 years old so it's not surprising that `scipy.misc.imread()` is deprecated. the docs suggest to use `imageio.imread` ; any option using `PIL` is preferable

Answer (score 14):

Up till now no one told about [matplotlib.image](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html):

```
import matplotlib.image as img
image = img.imread(file_name)
```

Now the image would be a 3D numpy array

```
print image.shape
```

Would be something like: `(317, 504, 3)`

Comment: it is giving image dimensions not converting image into matrix bro

Comment: @Salvador This is returning the shape of the image in which the first two arguments in the result give you the length and width respectively while the third one give you the dimension. and the question is asking about the matrix.

Comment: 'function' object has no attribute 'imread' ? 

x_test = [img.imread.imread(path, 'r') for path in x_test_paths]

Answer (score 7):

`scipy.misc.imread()` is deprecated now. We can use `imageio.imread` instead of that to read it as a Numpy array

Answer (score 6):

`im.load` in [`PIL`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) returns a matrix-like object.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [PyGame image](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) and use [PixelArray](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) to access the pixeldata

Comment: thanks - i will have to look into that. for now, i happened to have scipy and PIL installed already...

Answer (score 1):

Definitely try

```
from matplotlib.image import imread

image  = imread(filename)
```

The filename  preferably has to be an *.jpg* image.
And then, try

```
image.shape
```

This would return :

- **for a black and white or grayscale image**
  An **(n,n)** matrix where n represents the dimension of the images (pixels) and values inside the matrix range from 0 to 255. 
  Typically 0 is taken to be black, and 255 is taken to be white. 128 tends to be grey!
- **For color or RGB image**
  It will render a tensor of 3 channels. Each channel is an **(n,n)** matrix where each entry represents the respectively the level of Red, Green or Blue at the actual location inside the image.