# How to see the whole matrix of an image in python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to visualize how an image is represented as a matrix. I have used this answers perspective, [the 2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493092/convert-image-to-a-matrix-in-python) and used matplotlib.image module.

Now when I try to print the matrix, since the image consists of a large number of pixels, the matrix is not fully shown. How to see the full matrix?

I am using Anaconda compiler with Spyder as the IDE, all latest versions.

Comment: save the matrix into a file and then see the matrix. What would you do after seeing the matrix it is just numbers, you won't get any insights just by looking at the matrix

Comment: Resize the image so it's smaller maybe?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki how to write a matrix to a file? It can be pretty insightful if its just a b/w image

Comment: @MarkSetchell see the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use matplotlib to read the image and then save it as a file

```
In [21]: import json
In [22]: from matplotlib import image

In [23]: f = open("out.json", "w")

In [24]: c = image.imread("02.jpg")

In [25]: f.write(json.dumps(c.tolist(), indent=4))
Out[25]: 10925444

In [26]: f.close()
```

Comment: what is json? I don't work in javascript but thanks for ur help

Comment: Don't worry about the json. Just see the file out.json