# Matrix values for an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing

So, I am trying to convert a b/w image into its corresponding matrix. I have used the suggestion to convert into the matrix representation given in this answer.

[How to see the whole matrix of an image in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658061/how-to-see-the-whole-matrix-of-an-image-in-python)

The image is:
[image]

And the corresponding json file I got consisted mostly of `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`. Since the majority of the paper is white I am assuming `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]` stands for white.But how so? White is represented by `[255, 255, 255]`. So what exactly is happening here?

Comment: [The docu](https://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imread) isn't too explicit about its color encoding apart from saying that a MxNx3 Matrix corresponds to RGB. I'm assuming it just uses floats to encode the colour range instead of ints - so you just have to multiply them with 255 to get the result you expect.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel yeah i was also thinking the same coz it had some float values..if u write this as an answer i'll accept it and upvote it...ur choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what [the docu](https://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imread) implies, a result with MxNx3 dimensions implies RGB encoding. The only thing left to do then is to turn their representation (`float[0..1]`) into the one you want (`int[0..255]`):

```
with open('your_image.png', 'r') as img:
    image_as_floats = json.load(img)
image_as_ints = [[int(r*255), int(g*255), int(b*255)] for r, g, b, in image_as_floats]

with open('your_image_2.png', 'w') as img:
    img.write(json.dumps(img))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an RGB image. the easiest thing would be to use PIL.Image module and numpy

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
img_as_matrix = np.array(img)
np.savetxt('imagematrix.txt', img_as_mtrix, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

Comment: my main problem was writing it to a file