# How to differentiate between shades of gray in image below?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, color-space, lab-color-space

[image: In this Sat Image,2 buildings clusters are gray but they are different shades of gray]

I need to check if the color of gray is similar to one group of buildings vs other group.

What is the best approach to take using OpenCV or python image library? I feel like I have to use LAB color space to check the color space, but I am having hard time finding threshold of allowed difference to call them similar building vs different building.

is this ask super human?

Comment: What I would do is convert the picture to black&white, calculate average pixel values for each roof, and then select what would you consider 'similar' and add a group to each roof. Of course, first, you would have to write a code to select only the roofs. [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493092/convert-image-to-a-matrix-in-python)

Comment: Seperating houses is simple. The question is: How you will seperate the houses from environment, how you ll detect the houses ?

Comment: You can make @JonasPalačionis idea more simple i.e. without the need for an algorithm to find the roof. you can write a simple code that let you select two points (or a 2 centers of circles or anything similar) interactively and it will compare the GRAY component in the LAB space. then produces a TRUE/FALSE result.

Comment: Thanks for insightful answers. I have already segmented the houses. So, I do know polygons for each building. @Orb How do we calculate 'gray' component of LAB? will it be one of the 'L/A/B' value?

Comment: The L value runs from 0 to 100 with black and white limits. A and B components should be zero. See this for further insight..https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/416673-can-i-use-grayscale-image-in-lab-color-space

Comment: thanks @Orb, much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to split this into 2 seperate questions on SOF:
1) How do I detect/isolate the roofs and
2) How do differentiate between the colors; since your question is non-trivial as it is and probably won't get an adequate answer as this is a lot of effort no one is willing to make.

Comment: Thanks @TA , Yes I have detected roofs already and know the coords for the pixels for the same roof. I am having hard time finding the threshold, above which I can say colors are different. One Reason if most of sat images are gray/grayish.